# Camera intent onActivityResult code saves (blank) image even if photo was not accepted by user

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

When the user clicks the cross to not accept the photo, it ends the intent in the same way it does when they accept the photo they took. It saves a file to the device gallery. But it's blank. Shouldn't clicking the cross mean that resultCode != RESULT_OK? Is there one more check I am missing? Thanks. Here's the code. Wait, I'm saving the image before activity result...this is a flawed system, but it was on the official Android Developers website. If someone can suggest a fix I would be very greatful, because I used to save the image in onActivtyResult and it did not work on some phones, causing an exception, so I changed to this.

To start the intent:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
              Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
              if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                  // Create the File where the photo should go
                  File photoFile = null;
                  try {
                      photoFile = createImageFile();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                      // Error occurred while creating the File
                  }
                  // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                  if (photoFile != null) {
                      takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                              Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                  }
              }
          }  

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
              // Create an image file name
              String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
              String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
              File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
              File image = File.createTempFile(
                  imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                  ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                  storageDir      /* directory */
              );

              // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
              mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
              ih.galleryAddPic(mCurrentPhotoPath, this.getApplicationContext());
              return image;
          }
```

The camera intent case within onActivityResult:

```
else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) && (resultcode == RESULT_OK)){
                                              mProfilePicPath = mCurrentPhotoPath;
                                              mPortraitPhoto = ih.decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(mCurrentPhotoPath, 
                                                      GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION, 
                                                      GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION);
                                              TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id.ProfilePicText);
                                tv.setText(mProfilePicPath);
                          }
                  }catch(Exception ex){
                          Log.d("shkdghrfb", ex.toString());
                  }
          }
```

**EDIT:** I changed onActivityResult to this, but to no avail (the blank image is still in my gallery afterwards, and the value of deleted is true):

```
else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO){
                            if(resultcode == RESULT_OK){
                                File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                                mProfilePicPath = null;
                                if (f.exists()) {
                                    if (f.length() != 0){
                                          mProfilePicPath = mCurrentPhotoPath;
                                          mPortraitPhoto = ih.decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(mCurrentPhotoPath, 
                                                  GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION, 
                                                  GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION);
                                          TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id.ProfilePicText);
                                          tv.setText(mProfilePicPath);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                    boolean deleted = f.delete();
                                    if (deleted == true){
                                    Log.d("camera0", "deleted");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Log.d("camera0", "not deleted");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                            boolean deleted = f.delete();
                            if (deleted == true){
                            Log.d("camera", "deleted");
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.d("camera", "not deleted");
                            }
                        }
                  }
          }catch(Exception ex){
                  Log.d("shkdghrfb", ex.toString());
          }
              }catch(Exception ex){
                      Log.d("shkdghrfb", ex.toString());
              }
```

**Edit** Ok I believe I needed to scan the appropriate area of the SD card with a MediaScannerIntent after the delete, for it to show, as it seems to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you creating file with createImageFile() ?
You may save photoFile and on result!=RESULT_OK delete it

By the way, camera apps(even default) may return wrong result. Check it in logs. If they do, just don't rely on result & check created file's size. If ==0 - delete it

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. Will give it a go tomorrow. There is that, or only saving in onActivityResult which may be less work for the app to do, although I doubt it would make any performance difference.

Comment: I attempted it, and the blank image is still in the gallery. I put my attempt at the bottom of my question. Cheers. Note that mCurrentPhotoPath is set to the file.getAbsolutePath in `createImageFile()`

Comment: It works now. Maybe just add into the answer not to forget to scan the appropriate area of the SD card with a MediaScannerIntent after the deletion, otherwise it will not show the deletion yet, which is confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @user3164083 Sounds a bit too complex. Maybe you should try not to create real file in `createImageFile()`(still create a valid File object with a valid path there)

Comment: It's quite complex yeah. I will look into your suggestion when I refactor.